# How to check if href attribute is empty

Tags: jquery, html

In my markup, my A element has a href equal to `"": <a href="">`. When trying to display it though using an like for example `alert(jQuery('#my_href_link').attr('href'))`, it returns **"undefined"** rather than an empty chain or something.

So the solutions I found everywhere:

```
if (jQuery('#my_href_link').attr('href') == '')
```

or

```
if (jQuery('#my_href_link').attr('href').length == 0)
```

... don't work.

Yet they seem to work for everybody except me. Why is that?

Markup:

```
<a id="my_href_link" href="">
    <img src="image.jpg">
</a>
```

Comment: is href exist in your html? show your html..

Comment: Yes it does exist, I added the markup I see in Firebug to my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take advantage of the truthy and falsey nature of Javascript variables. In this if statement an empty string or undefined will cause the conditional to evaluate to false.

```
if (jQuery('#my_href_link').attr('href'))
```

You can easily negate this statement using `!` since the following == true:

```
alert(!undefined);
alert(!"");
```

[Read more about truthy and falsey](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Comment: Ok, I would like to made the opposite statement. Can I write the same thing with a "!" right before "jQuery"? I just tried and it seems to detroy my code execution.

Comment: The `!` should work.  How does it destroy your code execution can you provide an example?

Comment: My page's JS code is very complicated so there must be some intricate conflict somewhere. I'll deal with that, thanks anyway.

Comment: @drake035 Make sure your using a good editor that will highlight syntax errors such as Aptana.  You can also run your js through jsonlint which will help detect syntax errors.